# Android Buttons dont work click on click

Tags: android

I'm new new to Android and am working on a simple project that needs login and sign up.
When I click on the links to link to another activity, The buttons do not work.

here is my code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg_login"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:contentDescription="@string/Zilwacom_Logo" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome_to_zilwacom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.14" />

    <!--  Email Label -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginemail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/Email" />


    <!--  Password Label -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginpassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/Password"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnlogin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="@string/Login"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linksignup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

and my login code
When the user clicks to sign up, the app shd open the signup activity

```
 public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText email;
private EditText password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    //Get reference to buttons and texts

    //buttons
    Button loginbtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

    TextView signuplink=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.linksignup);

    //Texts
    email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginemail);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginpassword);

     signuplink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
           }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use `setOnClickListener` on your button as well. Was that the problem? Have you already added `setOnClickListener` on the button and getting some error?

Comment: Yeah, I did and I got the same error, 
I tried to re-do the whole project but still get the same error..

I want to use my Textview and make it clickable...(linksignup)

Comment: When I run the app, on click, nothing happens

Comment: Can you please post the code that is not working. The code that you have posted is not complete I assume. If you have already added `setOnClickListener` on the button, post that code in the question also.

Comment: You may want a `OnTouchListener` instead of a `OnClickListener` for a TextView

Comment: @SaumikBhattacharya, I just need this one TextView button to work and then I  see how to figure out the rest since am a learner

Comment: It seems nothing wrong in your code. Please update your question with `setOnClickListener` on the button. Then we can help you!

Comment: I have just test your code . It works pretty well ,maybe you haven't declare SignUpActivity as an intent in manifest.xml .

Comment: @ghassen92, 
Here is my Manifest.


        <activity android:name="com.daniels.zilwacom.SignupActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.daniels.zilwacom.SignupActivity"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

Comment: I have set this on the login button but still nothing happens when I tap.
 
          loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);

                //startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you tapped me", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

Comment: Try to change <activity android:name="com.daniels.zilwacom.SignupActivity"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.daniels.zilwacom.SignupActivity"/> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> </intent-filter> </activity>  to <activity android:name="com.daniels.zilwacom.SignupActivity">

Comment: @ghassen92, Tried but still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it guys, 
The problem was in the manifest...
I made the change as below..

```
   <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add/change in your code:

```
loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
           }
        });

    }
```

Set `onClickListener` to your `Button` [`loginbtn`] not `TextView` [`signuplink`].

In your xml layout file add to TextView android:clickable = "true"

Comment: loginbtn is to be used to login and linksignup is to be used to launch the signup activity in case a user needs to signup

Comment: @enockdaniels In your xml layout file add to TextView `android:clickable = "true"`